# Can we use procedure in a class constructor? If you can then how to use it?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am new to Salesforce, so I am stuck in this situation. I want to use the procedure `getHocSinh()` to get `HOCSINH__c` data for pageBlockTable on load. But my website shows me this error:
[image]

Only if I don't try to call the procedure `getHocSinh()` in class constructor. I really need help with this problem.
And by the way, how can I call styleClass in VisualForce Page, cuz I don't if using `document.querySelectorAll('.class')`  and want to know if there's a better way to call VisualForce Page component. Thank you.
This is my VisualForce Page code:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="TimKiemController">
    <apex:form >
        <!-- CSS -->
        <style>
            #Function{
                table-layout: fixed;
                width: 95%;
            }
            th.FunctionHeader{
                text-align: right;
                width: 100px;
            }
            .Ten, .Lop, #NgaySinhTu, #NgaySinhDen, .button{
                box-sizing: border-box;
                min-width: 10px;
                max-width: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        
        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function checkAll(cb){
                var inputElem = document.querySelectorAll('.checkOne');
                
                for(var i = 0; i < inputElem.length; i++)
                {
                    if(inputElem[i] != -1){
                        inputElem[i].checked = cb.checked;
                        if(inputElem.length > inputElem[i].checked.length){
                            inputElem[i] = -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        
            function checkOne(){
                var inputElem = document.querySelectorAll('.checkOne');
                var checkAll= document.querySelectorAll('.checkAll');
                
                for(var i = 0; i < inputElem.length; i++)
                {
                    if(inputElem[i] != -1){
                        if(inputElem[i].checked == false){
                            checkAll[0].checked = inputElem[i].checked;
                            break;
                        }
                        checkAll[0].checked = inputElem[i].checked;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
        
        <!-- HTML -->
        <table id="Function">
            <tr>
                <th class="FunctionHeader">Tên:</th>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!doituongTK.tenHS.TEN__c}" styleClass="Ten"/>
                </td>
                <td/>
                <td colspan="2"> 
                    <input id="TangDan" type="checkbox" value="{!doituongTK.tangdan}"/> 
                    Sắp xếp tăng dần theo tên 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="FunctionHeader">Lớp:</th>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <apex:selectList multiselect="false"
                                     size="1"
                                     value="{!doituongTK.tenLOP}"
                                     styleClass="Lop">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!lop}"/>
                    </apex:selectList> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="FunctionHeader"> Ngày sinh: </th>
                <td>
                    <input id="NgaySinhTu"
                           type="date"
                           value="{!doituongTK.ngaysinhTu.NGAYSINH__c}"/> 
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                    ~
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="NgaySinhDen"
                           type="date"
                           value="{!doituongTK.ngaysinhDen.NGAYSINH__c}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td/>
                <td>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Tìm kiếm"
                                        styleClass="button"/>
                </td>
                <td/>
                <td>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Thêm mới"
                                        styleClass="button"/>
                </td>
                <td/>
                <td>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Xóa"
                                        styleClass="button"
                                        onclick="if (!confirm('Bạn có muốn xóa?')){ return false; }"/>
                </td>
            </tr>                                         
        </table>
        <br/><br/>
        
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!dsHocSinh}" var="hs">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="checkAll" onclick="checkAll(this)" />
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="checkOne" onclick="checkOne()" value="{!hs.isChecked}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Họ" value="{!hs.hocsinh.HO__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Tên" value="{!hs.hocsinh.TEN__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Ngày sinh">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, date, dd/MM/yyyy}">
                        <apex:param value="{!hs.hocsinh.NGAYSINH__c}"/>
                    </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Giới tính" value="{!hs.hocsinh.GIOITINH__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Điểm 1" value="{!hs.hocsinh.DIEM1__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Điểm 2" value="{!hs.hocsinh.DIEM2__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Điểm 3" value="{!hs.hocsinh.DIEM3__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Điểm TB" value="{!hs.hocsinh.DIEMTB__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Tình trạng" value="{!hs.hocsinh.TINHTRANG__c}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="{!soluongHS}">
                    <apex:commandLink ><u>Cập nhật</u></apex:commandLink>
                    <apex:outputText value=" | "/>
                    <apex:commandLink ><u>Xóa</u></apex:commandLink>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and this is my Apex code:

```
public with sharing class TimKiemController {
    public List<danhsachHS> dsHocSinh { get; set; }
    public loaiTimKiem doituongTK { get; set; }
    
    public String idHS { get; set; }
    public String soluongHS { get; set; }
    
    public TimKiemController(){
        this.dsHocSinh = this.getHocSinh();
        this.soluongHS =  'Số lượng: '+ 3;
        this.doituongTK = new loaiTimKiem();
    }
    
    public class loaiTimKiem{
        public Boolean tangdan { get; set; }
        public HOCSINH__c tenHS { get; set; }
        public String tenLOP { get; set; }
        public HOCSINH__c ngaysinhTu { get; set; }
        public HOCSINH__c ngaysinhDen { get; set; }
        
        public loaiTimKiem() {
            this.ngaysinhTu = new HOCSINH__c();
            this.ngaysinhDen = new HOCSINH__c();
            this.tangdan = false;
            this.tenHS = new HOCSINH__c();
            this.tenLOP = '';
        }
    }
    
    public class danhsachHS{
        public HOCSINH__c hocsinh {get; set;}
        public Boolean isChecked {get; set;}
        
        public danhsachHS(HOCSINH__c hs){
            this.hocsinh = hs;
            this.isChecked = false;
        }
        public danhsachHS(){}
    }

    public PageReference chitiet(){
        String getIDHocSinh = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('idHS');
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/VF_ChiTiet?id=' + getIDHocSinh);
        
        return pr;
    }
    
    public PageReference capnhat(){
        String getIDHocSinh = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('idHS');
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/VF_CapNhat?id=' + getIDHocSinh);
        
        return pr;
    }
    
    public PageReference themmoi(){
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/VF_ThemMoi');
        pr.setRedirect(true);
        
        return pr;
    }
    
    public List<SelectOption> getLop(){
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<LOP__c> danhsachLop = [SELECT TEN__c FROM LOP__c];
        
        for(LOP__c lop : danhsachLop){
            options.add(new SelectOption((String)lop.get('TEN__c'), (String)lop.get('TEN__c')));
        }
        
        return options;
    }
    
    private List<danhsachHS> getHocSinh(){
        List<HOCSINH__c> getDanhSachHocSinh = 
            [
                SELECT HO__c, TEN__c, NGAYSINH__c, GIOITINH__c, DIEM1__c, DIEM2__c, DIEM3__c, DIEMTB__c, TINHTRANG__c
                FROM HOCSINH__c
            ];
        /*
        if(this.doituongTK.tenHS.TEN__c != null ||
          this.doituongTK.tenLop != null ||
          this.doituongTK.ngaysinhTu.NGAYSINH__c != null ||
          this.doituongTK.ngaysinhDen.NGAYSINH__c != null)
        {
            getDanhSachHocSinh = [SELECT HO__c, TEN__c, NGAYSINH__c, GIOITINH__c, DIEM1__c, DIEM2__c, DIEM3__c, DIEMTB__c, TINHTRANG__c
                                               FROM HOCSINH__c
                                               WHERE TEN__c LIKE : this.doituongTK.tenHS.TEN__c
                                               OR LOP__r.TEN__c LIKE : this.doituongTK.tenLop
                                               OR (HOCSINH__c.NGAYSINH__c > : this.doituongTK.ngaysinhTu.NGAYSINH__c
                                               AND HOCSINH__c.NGAYSINH__c < : this.doituongTK.ngaysinhDen.NGAYSINH__c)];
        }
        */
        List<danhsachHS> result = new List<danhsachHS>();
        for(HOCSINH__c hs : getDanhSachHocSinh){
            result.add(new danhsachHS(hs));
        }
        
        return this.sapXep(result, this.doituongTK.tangdan);
    }
    
    private List<danhsachHS> sapXep(List<danhsachHS> danhsach, Boolean tangdan){
        List<danhsachHS> result = new List<danhsachHS>();
        if(tangdan)
        {
            while(!danhsach.isEmpty()){
                String max = danhsach.get(0).hocsinh.TEN__c;
                danhsachHS maxObj = danhsach.get(0);
                for(danhsachHS hs : danhsach){
                    if(hs.hocsinh.TEN__c.compareTo(max) > 0){
                        max = hs.hocsinh.TEN__c;
                        maxObj = hs;
                    }
                }
                result.add(new danhsachHS(maxObj.hocsinh));
                danhsach.remove(danhsach.indexOf(maxObj));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while(!danhsach.isEmpty()){
                String min = danhsach.get(0).hocsinh.TEN__c;
                danhsachHS minObj = danhsach.get(0);
                for(danhsachHS hs : danhsach){
                    if(hs.hocsinh.TEN__c.compareTo(min) < 0){
                        min = hs.hocsinh.TEN__c;
                        minObj = hs;
                    }
                }
                result.add(new danhsachHS(minObj.hocsinh));
                danhsach.remove(danhsach.indexOf(minObj));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    /*
    public void timkiem() {
        try {
            if(String.isBlank(this.doituongTK.tenHS.TEN__c)){
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Tên không được để trống'));
                return;
            }
            this.dsHocSinh = this.getHocSinh();
            this.soluongHS =  'Số lượng: '+ this.dsHocSinh.size();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, ex.getMessage()));
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize a variable before you can use it:

```
    this.soluongHS =  'Số lượng: '+ 3;
    this.doituongTK = new loaiTimKiem();
    this.dsHocSinh = this.getHocSinh();
```

Comment: Holly shit, it works. After I initialize `this.soluongHS` like this : 

`public List<danhsachHS> dsHocSinh 
    { 
        get { return this.getHocSinh(); } 
        set { dsHocSinh = value; } 
    }`


It works. Thank you so much, kind sir.

Comment: sorry for the ugly format, it doesn't break the line.

Comment: @HungDoan Yeah, comments are kind of limited in what they can do. No worries, I've been here a long time, I'm used to it. That aside, I'm happy that I was able to help you overcome your problem.